# Vuetify v-app-bar doesn't shrink smoothly

Tags: vuetify.js

I faced following problem with v-app-var.
When I scroll down, I expect app bar to shrink smoothly and evenly, but instead it behaves laggy

Here is an example to see it yourself , but screen size must be set to 1440х900 in order to reproduce a problem
https://qx5v2.csb.app/

Here's a [video](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/caQR/GLpUoJB8e) how it looks like

Please help me out.

Answer (score -1):

**Just run these commands :**

```
<template>
    <v-app>
        <v-app-bar
            app
            class="light-blue"
            dark
            height="400"
            shrink-on-scroll
            fade-img-on-scroll
            src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1080?random"
        >
            <template v-slot:img="{ props }">
                <v-img
                    v-bind="props"
                    gradient="to top right, rgba(100,115,201,.7), rgba(25,32,72,.7)"
                ></v-img>
            </template>
        </v-app-bar>
        <v-main>
            <v-container fluid>
                <div>Lorem ipsum.</div>
                <div>Officia, quos!</div>
                <div>Modi, quas!</div>
                <div>Sapiente, fugiat!</div>
                <div>Facere, ex.</div>
                <div>Alias, quaerat!</div>
                <div>Exercitationem, vel.</div>
                <div>Eligendi, architecto.</div>
                <div>Minima, animi.</div>
                <div>Nulla, aspernatur.</div>
                <div>Consectetur, aliquid!</div>
                <div>Tempore, commodi.</div>
                <div>Odit, voluptas!</div>
                <div>Excepturi, iste.</div>
                <div>Optio, amet.</div>
                <div>Eos, laudantium.</div>
                <div>Facere, veritatis!</div>
                <div>A, architecto!</div>
                <div>Ad, tempora.</div>
                <div>Optio, expedita.</div>
                <div>Quasi, quas.</div>
                <div>A, consequatur.</div>
                <div>Aperiam, debitis.</div>
                <div>Quod, modi.</div>
                <div>A, consequatur.</div>
            </v-container>
        </v-main>
        <v-footer app absolute>
            <v-container>
                <v-row justify="center">
                    <div class="ma-4">
                        <v-btn icon>
                            <v-icon>mdi-magnify</v-icon>
                        </v-btn>
                        <v-btn icon>
                            <v-icon>mdi-facebook</v-icon>
                        </v-btn>
                        <v-btn icon>
                            <v-icon>mdi-instagram</v-icon>
                        </v-btn>
                    </div>
                </v-row>
            </v-container>
        </v-footer>
    </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'layout',
    components: {}
}
</script>
```